# Find all undefined variables in Ruby file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am coming across lot of production issues related to undefined variables. How can I FIND all undefined variables in Ruby file? Is there any gem/script which can scan through code files and detect possible issues.. This way I can test code before production deployment or accepting Pull Requests.

Answer (score 2):

This can't really be done. There are too many ways a variable *could* be defined. There's also an equal number of ways a variable that should be defined could be set to `nil` for whatever reason.

You can run Ruby with warnings enabled (`-w` on the command-line), which will complain vigorously about these things. It will only complain about variables along the execution path of the code, so if there are sections you don't exercise, you won't get warnings.

This is why having a test suite that exhaustively tests branches is essential to shaking out bugs like this. If you have an `if` in your code, you need two tests for it. If you have two `if` clauses, you may need three or four. Anything with a `case` will need all branches tested. This can be a lot of work for a project that's got a lot of business logic in it.

Since Ruby isn't compiled per-se, it's not really able to detect these sorts of issues before the code is run. What's in your file and what actually gets executed can be worlds apart depending on the impact of other parts of code. This is not true in more conservative languages like C or Rust.

Comment: Besides that the whole answer is great, the last sequence should be restated, IMHO. Eras ago I had written some C code for the proprietary software to prevent it from running unlicensed. No one single ruby app in the world does have as many levels of direct and indirect code generation. In fact C has “pass a control by this particular memory address,” which is way more cumbersome control flow breakage, than any ruby meta-development.

Comment: @mudasobwa While you can do a lot of masochistic things in C code, a plain `.c` file with no includes and `int x() { return 1+2; }` will always return `3`. This is not the case in Ruby. The output of `def x; 1+2; end` remains *completely* unknown until it's actually executed. Both C and Ruby have their bizarro dark world of ambiguity, but Ruby's means you can't take anything for granted. At least C is built up of independent `.o` files that tend to have some local cohesion. The linker can only do so much damage, and the runtime can only swap functions that are swappable.

Comment: Nope. Dynamically linked shared libraries might be substituted between two runs, while the virtual functions tables are more or less met :) Even more, as I have just pointed above, one might _overwrite_ your implementation of `int x() { return 1+2; }` directly in the memory in run time.

Comment: I know what you mean there, but I mean more *if* your function is run *then* you can be assured it returns `3`, that `+` doesn't suddenly do something bizarro. That's not the case in Ruby.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. Yes, to screw up `+` in `C` one should indeed use a soldering iron to patch the processor itself.

Answer (score 1):

Test Unit is built into rails so write some unit tests. Then run with rake test.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `rspec` and `simplecov` gems.

- `rspec` allows you to write unit tests that find undefined variables.
- `simplecov` measures code coverage to make sure your tests cover all variables.