# Can my editor alert me to undefined variables in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm familiar with python and needing to take on ruby development at my current job.
In setting up my editor I've noticed something that bites me far more often than I
like:

**My editor doesn't alert me to undefined variables in ruby**

From what I can gather, while Pylint will alert me to this in python, rubocop does not do
the same for ruby.

What I haven't been able to determine: Is there any possible way to fill this gap?

For reference, I use [neovim](https://neovim.io) with
[CoC](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) and
[Ale](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale). CoC is for completion, and runs the LSP. I'm
happy to throw another tool into the mix if needed.

Below is some contrived example code that, if fixed, is expected print:

```
omg
wtf
bbq
foo
bar
```

Python:

```py
# pylint: disable=missing-function-docstring,disallowed-name,missing-module-docstring
def omg():
    output = "omg"
    print(output)
    return output


def wtf():
    output = "wtf"
    print(output)
    return output


def bbq():
    output = "bbq"
    print(outtputt)
    return output


def foo():
    output = "foo"
    print(outtputt)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    omg()
    wtf()
    bbq()
    foo()
    print("bar")
```

Ruby:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

def omg
  output = 'omg'
  puts output
  output
end

def wtf
  output = 'wtf'
  puts output
  output
end

def bbq
  output = 'bbq'
  puts outtputt
  output
end

def foo
  output = 'foo'
  puts outtputt
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  omg
  wtf
  bbq
  foo
  puts 'bar'
end
```

Running vanilla `pylint` against the above python will give me:

```
python_var_error.py:16:10: E0602: Undefined variable 'outtputt' (undefined-variable)
python_var_error.py:22:10: E0602: Undefined variable 'outtputt' (undefined-variable)
python_var_error.py:21:4: W0612: Unused variable 'output' (unused-variable)
```

Whereas running vanilla `rubocop` against the above ruby will only give me:

```
ruby_var_error.rb:22:3: W: Lint/UselessAssignment: Useless assignment to variable - output. Did you mean outtputt?
  output = 'foo'
```

**What tool can I use (if any) to alert me to the error on line 17 in the above ruby?**

Everything I've found so far ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743989/find-all-undefined-variables-in-ruby-file)) seems to be roughly "ruby can't do it. You're SOL."

Comment: Statically deciding whether a variable is undefined in Ruby, is undecidable for the general case, although of course for local variables, there are many actual cases where a Ruby lexer can make a hint that a variable is most likely undefined. Such an editor most likely would compile the Ruby program with warnings turned on, and use the warning messages to point at such problem spots. I would not be surprised if someone has  tried this approach (did you already look at jEdit or Komodo? You can install several add-ons for various programming languages), but this is better asked at [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What tool can I use (if any) to alert me to the error on line 17 in the above ruby?

There is no (static) tool you can use to alert you to an error on line 17, because *there is no (static) error on line 17*. Line 17 is perfectly valid Ruby code, which calls a method named `outtputt` and passes the result as an argument to the method call to `puts`.

Since there is no (static) error, there cannot possibly be a (static) tool that shows the error.

Obviously, if the method is not defined, that will be a *runtime* error, and that will be caught by your tests.